# EM does not persist into db

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot and trying persist new object to db but nothing happened. I got the same method for another entity and it's works. Any suggestions?

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subject")
public class Subject implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "subject")
private Set<Question> questions =new HashSet<>();
```

**DAO:**

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
@Repository
@Transactional
public class QuestionDaoImpl implements QuestionDao {
public void createNewSubjectByName(String name) {
    Subject subject = new Subject();
    subject.setName(name);
    entityManager.persist(subject);
}
```

Comment: Is it raising any error? Put `@Transactional` in the `createNewSubjectByName` instead of the class

Comment: @Héctor no error method return. In debug my object is created but not persist. Adding annotation Transactional to method is not helped, i'm tryed

Comment: If you are using spring-boot why not using the `interface SubjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Subject, Integer> {}` setup and then use `@Autowired private SubjectRepository srepository;..srepository.save(...)`?

Comment: @khmarbaise tryed this just at the moment, but it's not working too. Db is still empty after method's call

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@Transactional
public Subject createNewSubjectByName(String name) {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    Subject subject = new Subject();
    subject.setName(name);
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(subject);
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
    return subject;
}
```

Comment: This may work, but it does not fix the problem beneath, which is that @Transactional is not working as expected. You might want to show the code of where and how createNewSubjectByName() is called.